# Command line prompt looks strange in virtual console

Tags: bash, virtual-console, ps1

In a terminal emulator like xterm my prompt looks like this:

```
[august@macmini ~]$
```

but in a virtual console the string `;linux` is prepended to the prompt to make it look like this:

```
;linux[august@macmini ~]$
```

Does anyone know where the "linux" string may come from?

Comment: show us your `$PS1` (and `$PROMPT_COMMAND` if you have one)

Comment: glenn jackman: Thanks for the hint. Apparently the prompt command is the source of the problem; when it is set to set the window title with `echo -ne "\033]0;$TERM\007"` it behaves strangely in console mode (where there is no window).

Comment: I've often seen in  a .bashrc `case $TERM in xterm*|rxvt*) PS1=...includes.window.title... ;; *) PS1=...no.title... ;; esac`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that things go wrong when a command to set the window title is executed in a virtual console (where there is no window). Changing

```
PROMPT_COMMAND='printf "\e]0;%s\a" "$TERM"'
```

to

```
if [[ $TERM = xterm* ]]; then
    PROMPT_COMMAND='printf "\e]0;%s\a" "$TERM"'
fi
```

solves the problem.

Comment: Since it's an xterm thing, I'd check if TERM is xterm instead. `if [[ $TERM = xterm* ]]; then PROMPT_COMMAND='printf "\e]0;%s\a" "xterm title here"'; fi`

Comment: geirha: OK, I didn't know it was xterm specific. I have updated my answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun, here's how I set my prompt:

```
# inspiration: http://www.stumbleupon.com/su/2LpQMi 
user_host_path="${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot) }"'\u@\h: \w'
xterm_title='\[\e]0;'"$user_host_path"'\a\]'
color_bold='\[\033[0;1m\]'
color_reset='\[\033[0m\]'
[[ $TERM == xterm* || $TERM == rxvt* ]] && first_part="${xterm_title}"
first_part+="\n${user_host_path}\n"
last_part='\! \$ '
PROMPT_COMMAND="((\$? != 0)) && PS1='${first_part}${color_bold}[\$?]${color_reset} ${last_part}' || PS1='${first_part}${last_part}'"
unset user_host_path xterm_title color_bold color_reset first_part last_part
```

Looks like this:

```
glennj@homebase: ~
200 $ (exit 42)

glennj@homebase: ~
[42] 201 $ cd /tmp

glennj@homebase: /tmp
202 $
```

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't crazy about the solution provided here since I use the same TERM for Ubuntu virtual terminals as other terminals (screen-256color). Thus, I took a quick look at what other environment variables could be useful for this purpose.

My conclusion was to use the XDG_VTNR (XDG virtual terminal number?) variable. Since Ubuntu uses VT#7 for the desktop environment, a simple check for whether this variable is greater than or equal to 7 does the trick.

I have bash function that builds my prompt anyway, so I just surrounded the title escape sequence addition with a check against the XDG_VTNR variable.

For example, note the **bolded** portion below:

```
# Use new test (i.e. [[ ]]) so as not to fail if XDG_VTNR does not exist
if [[ $XDG_VTNR -ge 7 ]]; then
  # Add the window title escape sequence to the prompt
else
  # Don't add the window title escape sequence to the prompt
fi
```

Just wanted to add this note in case it can be useful for anyone else.